# Can I apply for a tourism visa for my next trip to China while still in China?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas

Here is a situation:

- I first travel to China without visa, and while staying there apply for a tourism visa, which should be used on the next entry.
- After getting the visa, depart China to enter one of the Schengen countries, and then leave it to go back to China.
- When entering China, use the tourism visa.

So I would like to **apply for a visa that should be used on my next entry** while traveling visa-free. I heard it is not possible to have more than one visa simultaneously but in my case it is visa-free travel. So is this possible?

Comment: If you can enter China visa free anyway, why apply for a visa at all? You seem to be trying to game the system somehow, which I'd suggest is an inherently risky idea.

Comment: @Airsick Because of the length of stay. Visa-free entry allows me to stay for only up to 15 days.

Comment: Then why not apply for the visa you need before you travel and avoid the need to fly all the way to the Schengen area and back in the middle of your trip? I can't help but think that there's something you're not saying here. If this idea makes me suspicious I'd guess that the Chinese will be too.

Comment: @Airsick Because generally it is not possible to apply from  a country except your own. But I don’t live in my home country and won’t go back, so it is not possible to get the visa. The Schengen is just my current plan and it is fine to replace it with any countries.

Comment: @Airsick I keep traveling all year round without ever going back to my home country, so the only possible solution to get a Chinese visa is apply for it while in China. That is my question.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Validity,_number_of_entries_and_duration_of_each_stay_of_Chinese_visas) specifies home country applications for only seven countries, and even for those there are exceptions for those with residency or work permits in third countries. None of those seven qualify for 15-day visa free entry. Can I suggest you edit your question to clarify your reasons,  and include your own nationality.

Comment: @Airsick It is often considered that you must have a valid residence permit in the third country to apply for a visa, which I don’t. It is also reported that the rule varies greatly on each country. HK is considered more lax but I have no plan to visit it, and anyway it sounds risky - https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/application.htm It is fine to edit the question. I’m from Japan.

Answer (score 2):

First of all even if there is a possibility to get a Visa-on-arrival there is always the chance of the country to deny the entry of a person. China also grants itself this right. [see e.g. German official hints for entering China](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/chinasicherheit/200466) To have a planning security apply for a Visa upfront. This reduces On-arrival-denial.
Even if you have a valid Visa a country can always deny the entry of a person in specific cases. China also grants itself this right. 
When applying for the Visa you specifically sign the conditions for a granted Visa.

If you are already in China and try to get a longer valid stay this is really not easy to make it happen, see the comment and [link from Blaszard](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/application.htm).

**A common remark about Visa for China and stays longer than 30 days**
If you are still at home and plan to go to China and need to stay for a longer period than 30 days there are 3 ways, one good, one so-so and one bad:

- **Good** Apply for a Visa for longer stay (e.g. work visa), tourist Visa to my knowledge does not work. If granted you can stay there, no need to worry here.
- **So-so** Apply for multiple entry Visa. If you don't know a person in China you have to show valid flights and hotels for both stays.

  - To use your stays do the following: Just stay the first stay, on day 30 you can go to Shengzhen train station, walk to Hongkong and re-enter the country to stay your second stay.
- **Bad** A technique I absolutely do not recommend is to apply only for a 30 day entry and overstay it. I can absolutely not recomend this, it is quite costly (at this time it can cost if I remember correctly up to 15000 RMB) and this reduces your chance to re-enter China dramatically. In case you find you overstayed your Visa you should immediately go to the dedicated immigration center in the country to arrange things and pay the fine.

Source: Travelled to China quite a number of times. A close friend overstayed and had to pay the fine.

I wish everyone a good trip!